# Using an entity relationship diagram to document business processes

Tags: process, entity, relationship, diagram

Past exam question: How can you use an entity relationship diagram to document business processes?

As far as I know, I would use an ERD to document the relationships between data entities when designing a database. I can't see how ERD's can be used for business processes as flow charts are more suited for this. I would really appreciate if someone could give an example of how this is done.

All the examples I've found online relating to ERD's are for databases and not business processes.

- Thanks

Comment: This probably belongs on a different branch of stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this site. I just realized I could have posted it to 'Database Administrators'.

Comment: Welcome! I'm sorry if the community is ever harsh with you. We are sticklers for things being done in a correct manner! I hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a ER-Diagram to show the business processes. BPMN2.0 is a business process model notation with a wide variety of implementation on information technology. So process management can become a true beauty. If you want to take it further, it also allows Process Controlling in term of process roles, owners, editors, etc. There are a lot freeware designers available to fulfill your needs. I hope this answer helps you.

Regards

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was telling my professor but he keeps saying ERD's are for business processes also. He couldn't give an example tho!

Comment: @KirstenJay I agree with this answer. Data modeling is about organizing information/state. Processes are transitions between states, and orthogonal to the representation/structure of those states.